# objective C MKDropdownMenu how to change attributed Title?

Tags: objective-c, drop-down-menu

I'm a newbie in iOS programming. Today I download and use MKDropdownMenu in https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKDropdownMenu

I can not change the title of MKDropdownMenu in Navigation Bar. I want this text will be changed when user change the selected row.

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a NSString property `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *navTitle;`

set your default navigation title at `- (void)viewDidLoad` like

_navTitle =@"MKDropdownMenu";

change `- (NSAttributedString *)dropdownMenu:(MKDropdownMenu *)dropdownMenu attributedTitleForComponent:(NSInteger)component` method like this-

```
- (NSAttributedString *)dropdownMenu:(MKDropdownMenu *)dropdownMenu attributedTitleForComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_navTitle
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18 weight:UIFontWeightLight],
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
}
```

and change `- (void)dropdownMenu:(MKDropdownMenu *)dropdownMenu didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` like this-

```
- (void)dropdownMenu:(MKDropdownMenu *)dropdownMenu didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *colorString = self.colors[row];
    self.textLabel.text = colorString;
    _navTitle = colorString;

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:colorString];

    UIColor *color = UIColorWithHexString(colorString);
    self.view.backgroundColor = color;
    self.childViewController.shapeView.strokeColor = color;

    delay(0.15, ^{
        [dropdownMenu closeAllComponentsAnimated:YES];
        [dropdownMenu reloadAllComponents];
    });
}
```